# Display multiple divs side by side with only percentage width but a fixed margin

Tags: html, css

I want to display multiple div-tags side by side. When I display 4 divs then each div has a width of 25%. When I add a left-margin to each div of 20px the layout linebreaks because 4x25% + 4 x 20px = 100% + 80px. That will not work.

The box-sizing property does not consider the margin.

What I can do now is give each div a width of 16% which is 80% in total and every div also has a margin-left:5% which is 20% in total so its 100% all together. That should work.

But is there no better way? I just want fixed gaps between my divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer on Stackoverflow that works with this:

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/welcome/51959/edit)

wrap each of the four colored divs in a div that has style="width: 25%; float:left;"

The advantage with this approach is that all four columns will have equal width and the gap between them will always be 5px * 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

Here is a similar **[WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/y3pC3/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="abc">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#abc {
height: 125px;
text-align: justify;
border: 10px solid black;
font-size: 0.1px; /* IE 9 & 10 don't like font-size: 0; */
min-width: 600px;
}
#abc div {
width: 150px;
height: 125px;
display: inline-block;
background: red;
}
#abc:after {
content: '';
width: 100%; /* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper_2">
        <div id="child">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper_2">
        <div id="child">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper_2">
        <div id="child">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper_2">
        <div id="child">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#wrapper_2 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%; /* Number of element you want (here 100/4) */
}
#child {
  display:block;
  background-color:red;
  width:80%; /* Size of the element (100% => full cell) */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center the element in the table cell*/
}
```

JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/hJPBz/

Comment: it seems to get the table behavior we had for a decade...we will use display:table again and again the next decade :P